# target sibling of 'this', with nth-child

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target the nth sibling of a clicked item.
Basically to target next element that is nth(4n+4), to be able to insert a new element after that, kind of like on a "new line".

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).next('li:nth-child(4n+4)').after('<li class="full">new full width item</li>');
});
```

It's the .next('li:nth-child(4n+4)') that doesn't seem to work.

It's a bit hard to explain, but you will understand what I mean here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hYE7e/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually working fine, but `after()` will only be executed, when the very next `li` is 4n+4 child.
I.e. right from the start, it will work fine if you click on 3 *or* on 7. Right after you clicked on 3, the 7th one will stop working and 6th one will work instead, because 7 has now become 8th element.

A bit clumsy update: http://jsfiddle.net/hYE7e/3/

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n)").addClass("last-in-line");
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll("li.last-in-line").andSelf(".last-in-line").filter(":first").after('<li class="full">new full width item</li>');
});
```

`andSelf(".last-in-line").filter(":first")` to ensure that clicking on 4th, 8th, etc elements will work.

**Update:**

After discussion in comments, I think I have it: http://jsfiddle.net/hYE7e/7/

With custom filter:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    var myIndex = $("li:not(.full)").index($(this)); // Save our position in a row
    $(this)
      .nextAll("li:not(.full)")
      .andSelf()
      .filter(function(index){  // Get 4n'th lis from 'not(.full)' set
          return (index + myIndex + 1) % 4 == 0;  
      })
      .add("li:last")  // Make sure last rows will work
      .first()         // Only add 'li' after first matching element
      .after('<li class="full">new full width item</li>');
});
```

Comment: Oh I see! I want it to work on all elements of course, but to insert the new element after the "last-of-line = nth(4n+4)". Any tips? It's supposed to work a little bit like Google Images, when you click on an image it's opened in a box below that "line of images".

Comment: Although a good response, this isn't an answer but an educated explanation of the problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine. A little bit better than @SebastianG solution. But I still have two issues with this. 1) The items of the last line doesn't really work how I want, I want the new full width item to be added after that line. 2) It will be a dynamic listing adding new items on top, so that will mess up the "last-in-line" class. I could recalculate every time I add new items, but there might be a better solution. Sebastians solution might not have this problem (?)

Comment: Well... you still need to distinguish newly added li's from the ones you have (to get 4n'th elements).
If initial li's are dynamic and inserted li's are dynamic, and both have different meaning - it should be separated with classes.

Comment: There you go :) Thanks. I like where you are trying to go with update 5 and 6, since that would solve adding new li's, and not having to recalculate "last-of-line". But there seem to be other issues with this approach, clicking item 3, 8, 7, shows some issues.

Comment: Yep, that does not work :( nth-of-type/nth-child ignore prefiltered data. I'll play around and let you know, this is interesting :)

Comment: Thank you for your help mishik! I don't really understand what you did in the custom filter. Will have to study that further. But it does seem to work!
I made an other update to simulate new items, which breaks the code a bit. Can't click on newly added items, and clicking on 3, "add, 7, makes the new "li.full" be added in the wrong place. http://jsfiddle.net/hYE7e/8/

Comment: To have newly generated items working look for ".on()": http://api.jquery.com/on/
For example: `$("body").on("click", "li:not(.full)", function(){...});`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to filter all ucoming siblings, not only the next one, right? Perhaps this is what you want:

```
$(this).nextAll('li:nth-child(4n+4)').first().after('<li class="full">new full width item</li>');
```

See my [updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s4seS/).

Comment: Almost! I only want the new element to be inserted once, after the FIRST/NEXT nth(4n+4) sibling. Kind of like how Google Images work when you click on an image.

Comment: I like it. But it doesn't really do it how I want it. If I keep adding new lines, it's doesn't do it correctly after a while. I tried to tweak the code by adding a class to the original items, and only filter on those: http://jsfiddle.net/s4seS/1/ But still doesn't work the way I want. And the items on the last line doesn't work at all.